# How to show a message to user when another login occurs?

Tags: laravel, firebase, pusher

I want show a message to the user when more than one login is performed. For example, a user called John is logged into Computer A. Now John logs into Computer B. In this case system should show a message to John on Computer A that another login has happened.

In my opinion, this could be done using a push notification service such as Pusher or Firebase Cloud Messaging. Is that correct? or is there another way of doing this.

I'm storing the user's sessions in the database as soon as the login is performed so I can fire an event when more than the desired logins are performed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Laravel pretty much as the basics built in to allow for this. If you look into the default `boostrap.js` file Laravel ships with, you can see the code is already there: see https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/resources/js/bootstrap.js#L32-L41

If using Laravel's echo server you've broadcast events as described [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting#broadcasting-events). Within your application you'd listen for events as explained [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting#listening-for-events)

You could also make this even simpler (although I'd recommend websockets).

You could stgore "active" logins in your database and display a message based upon that.

Note that you can avoid multiple logins. When logging out you invalidate other sessions. This feature is built into Laravel, see [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#invalidating-sessions-on-other-devices).